# How to specify a cocoa pod asset target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have created a cocoa pod framework that includes some image assets. These assets are included in the pod spec and I can see the image when I inspect the framework, however I'm unable to access it from my app. When I inspect the assets in the "Development Pods" section I noticed that the target is a bundle called Zapic-Zapic instead of the target Zapic. If I change the target membership to just "Zapic" everything works as expected and I can access the image via the bundle. How do I change the target in my framework so that if I don't need to manually change the target?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After spending hours trying to figure this out i discovered this was being put in a separate bundle because my spec file was defining 
`s.resource_bundles = { 'Zapic' => 'Zapic/ZapicAssets.xcassets'}`. This creates a new bundle with just the resources, hence the Zapic-Zapic bundle. Once I changed it to `s.resource = 'Zapic/ZapicAssets.xcassets'` everything works as expected. It looks like the CocoaPod docs need to be updated now that dynamic frameworks are supported. I discovered this via an open issue on [CocoaPods Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5192). Hopefully this will save someone else from dealing with the same pain I just went through.

Answer (score 2):

**Great Daniel, Above answer is correct:)**

Earlier we had to manually select the Pod target then clean and build but start facing really issue when integrating CI. I spent hours to find out why its creating another target for resoruce_bundle but not for resources (contains custom font). Finally it worked now.

```
 sp.source_files  = "POD_PATH/**/*.{swift,xib}","POD_PATH/Font/open-sans/*.{ttf,txt,xib}"

 sp.resources = 'POD_PATH/Assets.xcassets'
```